# Multi-user desktop application, what approach for storage?

Tags: c#, database, desktop-application

I am currently building a new desktop application in C# that will store data common to all users of the application. It will be used by 10-15 people within a company and the data stored are recently used values.

My idea is currently to use SQLite and have the application on a common network disk, so every user opens the program from the same location. This is not a very flexible solution and the company really wants the application available on the go. It should also not be dependant on internet connection, so I guess there need to be some sort of synching between a user and central database when available.

What approach should I take?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server or Oracle or My SQL.
My SQL is free version.
SQL Server Express edition, It's free.
I have no idea about Oracle.